Can NRVO and Move Semantics Be Used Together in C++?
I'm reading about move semantics in C++ from the book C++ Move Semantics. The book assumes NRVO is used in the createAndInsert() function's return statement. However, it also states that move semantics are applied when v = createAndInsert(); is executed in main().
My question is: If NRVO is already applied, shouldn't coll be constructed directly in the space for v, thus making any move operations unnecessary in main()? Could this be for learning purposes in the book, or is it suggesting what happens if NRVO were not applied, despite stating it is? I'm trying to understand if I'm missing something about how NRVO and move semantics interact in this scenario.
Thanks for your insights!
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> createAndInsert()
{
    std::vector<std::string> coll;  // create vector of strings
    coll.reserve(3);                // reserve memory for 3 elements
    std::string s = "data";         // create string object

    coll.push_back(s);              // insert string object
    coll.push_back(s+s);            // insert temporary string
    coll.push_back(std::move(s));   // insert string (we no longer need the value of s)

    return coll;                    // return vector of strings
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;     // create empty vector of strings
    //...
    v = createAndInsert();          // assign returned vector of strings
    //...
}


NRVO is not mandatory. Also see Implicit move rule

Basically, as long as it is move-eligible and can be a implicitly movable entity and so an xvalue. See the answer.

I hope NRVO is used here ... I have written a lot of code that assumes that it is. I love C++ but I always have the worry in the back of my mind about what the compiler is actually doing. When I programmed in C I didn't have those worries. Actually I would never return a large value object in C, even though I think the extra copy is elided.

If you were to do std::vector<std::string> v = createAndInsert();, first there would be a move from coll to the returned temporary (NRVO may or may not elide it), then another move from that temporary to v (this is always elided since C++17).
But when doing std::vector<std::string> v; v = createAndInsert();, the second move can never be elided, because the object is already constructed.

Thanks for the answer! So, here with std::vectorstd::string v = createAndInsert();, the compiler either performs NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization) or applies move semantics. If NRVO is applied, the additional move from the temporary to v will be elided, effectively transforming 'coll' directly into 'v'. If move semantics are used instead, then the move operation transfers the temporary return value into v. Am I correct?

@Sami Not entirely. The move of temporary into v is always elided. The preceding move of coll into the temporary may or may not be elided (elided if compiler performs NRVO).

With NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization):
If NRVO applies: The local coll in createAndInsert() is constructed directly where v will be, eliminating any move operations.
If NRVO doesn't apply: coll is moved to a temporary object that holds the return value.
Without NRVO:
    First move: coll is moved to a temporary return object.
    Second move: This move (from the temporary to v) is elided in C++17 due to mandatory copy elision, meaning the temporary is constructed directly as v. AM i correct?


@Sami Yes, sounds correct.

With NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization):
If NRVO is applied:
The local object coll inside the function createAndInsert() is constructed directly in the memory location that v will occupy once the function returns. This skips any need to move the object since coll is essentially constructed as v.
If NRVO is not applied:
There isn't a direct construction of coll to v. Instead, coll needs to be moved to a temporary object that represents the return value of createAndInsert().
Without NRVO:
Move from coll to the returned temporary:
When NRVO is not applied, the vector coll is moved to a temporary object created to hold the function's return value. This is the first move operation mentioned.
Move from the temporary to v:
Before C++17, this would be a second move operation, where the temporary is moved to initialize v. However, since C++17, this move is elided by mandatory copy elision rules, effectively constructing the temporary directly in the space allocated for v.
What Happens in Each Case:
Initialization (std::vector<std::string> v = createAndInsert();):
If NRVO applies, coll transitions directly to v with no moves involved.
If NRVO doesn't apply, coll is moved to a temporary, and then this temporary is constructed in place as v (with the second move elided since C++17).
Assignment (std::vector<std::string> v; v = createAndInsert();):
Regardless of NRVO, since v is already constructed, the vector from createAndInsert() (whether it was coll or a temporary) is moved into v using move assignment, and this move cannot be elided.
